# Recasting where two types share a common base type

Tags: c#, casting

We have some code like the following:

```
    class Base
    {
        public string Name;
    }

    class DeeperBase : Base
    {
    }

    class A : Base
    {
        public A()
        {
            Name = "A";
        }
    }

    class B : DeeperBase
    {
        public B()
        {
            Name = "B";
        }
    }

    static T Recast<T>(Base original) where T : Base, new()
    {
        if (!original.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
            throw new InvalidCastException();
        return new T();
    }
```

It looks like `Recast` is trying to check if the two types are compatible before returning a new `T`. The method fails, however, for the following code.

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = new A();
        var b = Recast<B>(a); // exception
    }
```

What's the proper way to check that `T` and `original` share the greatest common base type (in this case, `Base`)?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @Anton Gogolev In `Recast`, is there a way to check that `original` and `T` share a base type? I feel that there should be a way, and that we must be doing something wrong if an exception is being thrown.

Comment: on your Recast Method. (Base original) declared this way is a concrete type, so it fails because you are trying to pass the concrete class 'DeeperBase' as opposed to a type of Base. You would need to pass in a 'generic' as well.

Comment: Your code is not trying to cast A into a base type, it's trying to cast it to B which is clearly nonsense.

Comment: I guess you are trying to check if both types has common parent. In that case you should use condition: if (!original.GetType().BaseType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))). But even better for you is to use automapper (emit mappet etc.) and map A to B, because such  cast has no sense. Again, as @AntonGogolev asked, it is not clear what your goal is.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to cast an instance `A` to `B`, which it can't, since they are not the same type, nor does `A` derive from `B`.

There is no way to cast `A` to `B`. You could do a `Recast<Base>(a)`, but that doesn't make sense. Note that you are not actually changing the type in any way, you are just returning a new instance of `B`, or throw an exception.

Comment: Our code stores all objects in a dictionary of type `Base`. `Recast` isn't supposed to return a cast of `original`, but instead replaces `original` with `T` in the dictionary. I guess I'm not really sure what the check is supposed to do, since `T` and `original` will always share `Base`.

Comment: Define "casted type". There is nothing useful going on here.